# I need to search into a specific field in MongoDB. Is it possible?

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

I have a multikey index and I need to do a text-search in only one of them. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you update your question to include more details and a specific example?

Comment: Example: I have a document that contains Books titles and the Author`s names.. I have a fulltext index on "title" and "authors.name". I need to search for "j k rowling" but using only "authors.name" (it's not a filter! it's a text search)

Answer (score 0):

If you create a Compound Index on 2 fields like this :

```
db.myCollection.ensureIndex({"field1":1,"field2":1})
```

Your index will be used in two case :

```
db.myCollection.find({"field1":"foo"})
```

and

```
db.myCollection.find({"field1":"foo","field2":"foo2"})
```

With a compound index, only the first field of the index defined will be used. if you make a search on it.

To check if your index is used, add .explain() after your request like this :

```
db.myCollection.find({"field1":"foo"}).explain()
db.myCollection.find({"field1":"foo","field2":"foo2"}).explain()
```

you will get a json response like this :

```
{
   "cursor" : "BtreeCursor field1_1_field2_1",
...
}
```

but if you make a search only on the second field like this :

```
db.myCollection.find({"field2":"foo"}).explain()
```

you will get a json response like this :

```
{
"cursor" : "BasicCursor"
}
```

it means that the query doesn't used your index

**So, yes you can, but only if the query is on the first Field defined in the compound index**

cordialy